# angular js upload file function does't work as expected

Tags: python, angular, flask

using angular to make upload file function and flask as the backend server.
However when I try to upload the file , always get error message.
Here are the codes.

HTML Elements:

```
        <input class="paper-trade__upload-button_hidden" type="file" id="csv-upload" name="file" accept=".csv" ngf-max-size="2MB" (change)="csvToArray($event)">
```

Angular:

```
    csvToArray(fileInput: any) {
    const hotInstance = this.hotRegisterer.getInstance(this.instance);
    let fileReaded = fileInput.target.files[0];
    this.tradeCaptureService.uploadPaperTradeCSV('KGI', 
    fileReaded).subscribe();
    }
```

the request body:

```
uploadPaperTradeCSV(brokerName: string, file): Observable<Trade> {
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
  }),
};
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

return this.http.post<Trade>(`${this.baseUrl}/trade/upload?broker_name=${brokerName}`, formData, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(data)),
);
```

}

Backend codes(python): as the request.files the requirments, send the file data as form-data

```
    @hello.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@jwt_required
def import_trades():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        broker_name = request.args.get('broker_name', '')
        data = request.form.get('file')

        if 'file' not in request.files:
            return jsonify({'fail': 'no file found'})
        file = request.files['file']
        if not file.filename:
            return jsonify({'fail': 'no file selected'})
        file_format = file.filename.split('.', 1)[1].lower()
        allowed_extension = set(['csv'])
        if file and file_format in allowed_extension:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            response = trade_orm.convert_file_data(broker_name, file_path)
            if os.path.exists(file_path):
                os.remove(file_path)
            return response
        else:
            return jsonify({'fail': 'please input valid info'})
```

However I try to upload the file , it always return 'no file found' message.Buy when using Postman to send request, it works fine.I stuck here for quite long time ..... 
Any help would be great appreciated, thanks for the help

Comment: And what is the error message

Comment: 'no file found',  somehow it just can't find the key word 'file' in the reqeust.files.

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution for this issue, remove the 'const httpOptions = {}' staff in uploadPaperTradeCSV() method, then the would work well.so the new code would be like this

```
uploadPaperTradeCSV(brokerName: string, file): Observable<Trade> {

let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file);

return this.http.post<Trade>(`${this.baseUrl}/trade/upload?broker_name=${brokerName}`, formData, httpOptions)
  .pipe(
    tap(data => console.log(data)),
);
```

but still I cant figure out why...